# How to find where my code is running with lldb

Tags: c++, lldb

I have a big project (more specifically `LibO`). While reading the whole docs and code costs too much time, I just want to know where my code is running without setting breakpoints because I know a little about the project.

That is, I want a command that pauses the program and shows the whole calling stack. Is there anything like it?

Comment: I don't know lldb, but normally when running under a debugger there's a way to pause your program. In command-line gdb, this would be Ctrl+C, and in an IDE there's probably a button. Then you can inspect the call stack and continue running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much the same between gdb and lldb.  On the command line ^C interrupts the process, `bt` backtraces the current thread, `bt all` does the same for all the threads.

Note you can also easily get a picture over time of what code is used in an app by running the "sample" tool from the command line, like:

```
$ sample ProcessName
```

That will interrupt the program you specify every 10 milliseconds for 10 seconds (you can change those numbers by passing time and interval as extra arguments) and then write out a report of all the stacks it saw in that time.

Comment: If you are familiar with gdb, there's a page here: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html that has a map from most of the common gdb commands to their lldb equivalents.